# ScrollView won't Scroll at all

Tags: react-native

I have a React page that needs a Scrollview, there's no way around it. The content goes off the bottom of the screen, and it is encapsulated in the ScrollView. I have a red border on the ScrollView element so I can see that it goes past the bottom of the screen where the rest of my content it. However, it just does not want to scroll. I even put an 'onScroll' prop inside with `console.log('hit')` at one point to see if the ScrollView was even registering my attempts, it was not. This is happening in a couple of similar components, their structure is very similar. The smallest of them looks like this...

```
 <ScrollView style={{borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 3}}>
            <View style={QualityStyles.container}>
                <View style={{width: '100%'}}>
                    <Text style={QualityStyles.leadersTitle}>Top Three Leaders</Text>
                </View> 
                <View style={QualityStyles.topThree}>
                    {renderTopThree(topThree)}
                </View>
                <View style={{width: '100%'}}>
                    <Text style={QualityStyles.leadersTitle}>Employees</Text>
                </View> 
                <View style={QualityStyles.remainders}>
                    {renderOthers(others)}            
                </View>
            </View>
            </ScrollView>
```

The code's pretty straightforward, with `renderTopThree` returning 3 components that will take up about 90% of the screen, and `renderOthers` will fit maybe one component on the screen, and the rest (while rendered and existent) can't be seen since I can't scroll. Anyone see what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue, I had a TouchableWithoutFeedback wrappping the entire Application, and it was blocking out any ability to scroll

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).